# packaging a spring boot jar for spark submit using gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spark-submit

Facing a ClassNotFoundException on then main class when I run the spring boot packaged JAR built by gradle on spark:

```
spark2-submit --class com.test.DriverMain test.jar ...
```

I'm using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE`

I've tried also removing the --class reference to the main class name, got passed on the ClassNotFoundException but later I ran into a lot of ClassCastException during the run:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.functions$$anonfun$14.f$10 of type org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1 in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.functions$$anonfun$14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the spark docs (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), it has links for sbt and maven plugins on how to package a compatible jar for submitting on spark (however there is none for gradle).

The jar structure output of the spring-boot-gradle-plugin is as follows:

```
test.jar
- BOOT-INF
  - lib
     - ... jars dependencies 
  - classes
     - com \ test \ ...
- org
  - springframework \ boot \loader \ ...
- META-INF
  - MANIFEST.MF
```

The expected structure is something like:

```
test.jar
- com \ test \ ...
- jar dependencies in package and classes format like org \ springframework \ data \ jpa \ ...
```

Here's a working snippet for gradle:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories repos
        dependencies {
            classpath com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0
        }
    }
    ...
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
    
    // this way I won't be needing any spring boot gradle related plugin for packaging and dependency mgt
    dependencies {
        implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.0.RELEASE")
        ...
    }
    // set to false, else it will be packaged twice, one for the shaded jar, one with the normal jar
    jar {
        enabled = false
    }
    // creates the spring boot shaded jar
    import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.PropertiesFileTransformer
    shadowJar {
        zip64 true
        mergeServiceFiles()
        append 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
        append 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
        append 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
        transform(PropertiesFileTransformer) {
            paths = ['META-INF/spring.factories' ]
            mergeStrategy = "append"
        }
        archiveFileName = "test-${version}.jar"
    }
    // shaded jar will be built whenever jar is being invoked
    jar.dependsOn(shadowJar)
```

Reference link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1828#issuecomment-231104288